# Flutter - How to detect if any background sound is playing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio, background

I'd like to know if a system's or any other player(like Spotify, SoundCloud etc.) is currently playing in the background. Basing on that, I'd on or off my app's sounds. From Flutter's level, how to get access to information about it (iOS&Android)?

Comment: This could help: https://pub.dev/packages/nowplaying